# CakePhp 3.x - Disable Postlink Button

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to show a gif while the post is being made? Or how can the button be disabled to avoid more than one execution?

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-button-text', function(){
    $('#image-b-loading').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: This is entirely a jQuery question, nothing to do with CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid more than one execution you can add an attribute after clicking the link and doing nothing if the attribute already exists. Like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-button-text', function(){
    if (!$(this).attr('data-already-executed')) {
        $(this).attr('data-already-executed', '1'); 
    }
}
```